# Ninject to Simple Injector : Register filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, simple-injector

I am migrating from Ninject to Simple Injector due to better performance in my MVC 3 application. I can register the repositories and services fine. But there is a filter that is registered in Ninject using

`kernel.BindFilter<UserActivityAttribute>(FilterScope.Controller, 0).WhenControllerHas<UserActivityFilter>();`

which doesn't translate to Simple Injector. Basically we use that filter to log user activity and UserActivityFilter is specified as an attribute for the controller for which logging is required.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `BindFilter` equivalent in Simple Injector. Since I'm not familiar with that Ninject feature, I can't tell you how to simulate it (although it's possible of course).

What you can do of course is mark your controllers with filter attributes, but this is probably something you are trying to prevent in the first place (if I understand what that Ninject's `BindFilter` feature does).

Personally, I'm a fan of applying cross-cutting concerns (such as logging) using decorators. You can either apply a decorator at the service layer boundary (such as is [this article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) shows) or apply decorators at the controller level.

Applying decorators around controllers needs a bit more work. You'll need to change the way you registered your controllers for this. This will likely be your current registration:

```cs
container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

To be able to apply decorators you will have to register controllers by their base type (`IController` in this case). There are multiple ways to do this, but I like this approach:

```cs
// We get all controller types for the current assembly.
var controllerTypes = SimpleInjectorMvcExtensions
    .GetControllerTypesToRegister(container,
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// Here we register a collection of controllers.
container.RegisterAll<IController>(controllerTypes);

// We register a custom IControllerActivator.
container.RegisterSingle<IControllerActivator>(() => 
    new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(
        container.GetAllInstances<IController>(),
        controllerTypes));
```

Since controllers are registered by their `IController` base type, we can now apply decorators around controllers:

```cs
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IController),
    typeof(UserActivityControllerDecorator), c =>
    c.ImplementationType.GetCustomAttribute<UserActivityFilter>()
        .Any());
```

Instead of mapping controllers to their concrete type (using `Register<HomeController>()` or Ninject's `Bind<HomeController>().ToSelf()`, we now register them as a collection. The custom `IControllerActivator` can now get specific items from the collection:

```cs
// using System.Linq;

internal sealed class SimpleInjectorControllerActivator 
    : IControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IController> controllers;
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, int> mapping;

    public SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(
        IEnumerable<IController> controllers, 
        Type[] controllerTypes)
    {
        this.controllers = controllers;

        // Here we make a mapping from the controller type to
        // the index in the controllers collection.
        this.mapping = controllerTypes
            .Select((type, index) => new { type, index })
            .ToDictionary(i => i.type, i => i.index);
    }

    public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, 
        Type controllerType)
    {
        int index = this.mapping[controllerType];
        return controllers.ElementAt(index);
    }
}
```

The `Create` method makes use of the `Enumerable.ElementAt` method 
to get a specific (decorated) controller from the collection by its index. Collections returned by Simple Injector implement `IList<T>` and this allows `ElementAt` use `IList<T>` indexer which allows this operation to have performance characteristic of O(1). The performance of the call to `ElementAt` will not degrade when the number of controllers increases.

With this you can write your decorators as follows:

```cs
class UserActivityControllerDecorator : IController
{
    private readonly IController decoratee;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public UserActivityControllerDecorator(IController decoratee,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        this.logger = logger;        }

    public void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        // do something before executing the controller
        this.decoratee.Execute(requestContext);
        // do something after executing the controller      
    }
}
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. It doesn't seem to recognise ImplementationType.GetCustomAttribute

Comment: @PrithviRamana: In that case, you're probably running on .NET 4.0. [GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292.aspx) is new in .NET 4.5 (and is one of the small little improvements Microsoft added in that release).

Comment: I added it as a global filter for now and handled everything inside the UserActivityAttribute as my application cannot be upgraded to 4.5 yet. Thanks.

Comment: .NET 4.0 contains non-generic GetCustomAttribute methods, so the omission of that extension method shouldn't be a limiting factor.